# Elixir getting information from a list of maps

Tags: elixir

I have this structure being sent to me via post: `contacts = [%{"John" => ["0724573977"]}, %{"Mary" => ["0724573111", "0744556778"]}]` which is basically a list of contacts with each contact being a map `name => phone_numbers`

I'm trying to make a list with all the phone numbers, ignoring any names, just a list of numbers:

```
a = [%{"1" => ["0724573977"]}, %{"2" => ["0724573111", "0744556778"]}]

p = Enum.reduce a, [], fn(contact, acc) ->
    for {_record_id, phones} <- contact do
        for phone <- phones do
            acc ++ phone
        end
    end
end

IO.inspect p
```

This one produces: `[[[["0724573977"] | "0724573111"], [["0724573977"] | "0744556778"]]]` which is odd but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be idiomatic Elixir as I'm new to the language but this works for me:

```
iex(11)> List.flatten(Enum.map(a, fn(x) -> Map.values(x) end))
["0724573977", "0724573111", "0744556778"]
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many correct answers already posted, but I thought I'd post my preferred solution: use a `for` with 3 `<-`:

```
iex(1)> contacts = [%{"1" => ["0724573977"]}, %{"2" => ["0724573111", "0744556778"]}]
[%{"1" => ["0724573977"]}, %{"2" => ["0724573111", "0744556778"]}]
iex(2)> for contact <- contacts, {_, phones} <- contact, phone <- phones, do: phone
["0724573977", "0724573111", "0744556778"]
```

(I particularly dislike `List.flatten/1` based solutions since they'll not work the same way if the last level data was a list instead of a string. That functions flattens every list at any depth. It doesn't matter for this particular case though since your last level of data is a list of strings.)

Comment: This is the best solution here so far and this should be marked as a correct answer. @RomeoMihalcea please note the explanation why `List.flatten/1` should be in general avoided when used with well-determined structures.

Answer (score 3):

To get just a list of numbers one might use:

```
contacts
|> Enum.map(&Map.values/1)
|> List.flatten
#⇒ ["0724573977", "0724573111", "0744556778"]
```

To substitute names with numbers, one might use `Enum.with_index` in the middle of the chain.

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler to do:

```
a
|> Enum.flat_map(&Map.to_list/1)
|> Enum.flat_map(a, fn {_record_id, phones} -> phones end)
```

The problem with the code you tried though is that each iteration of `for` produces an element in a new list, and additionally because Elixir is immutable, you aren't actually changing `acc` you are creating elements which append each phone number to the same list, hence the unexpected list of lists you get in the end.

Comment: Looks fantastic but..`** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erl_eval."-inside-an-interpreted-fun-"/1`

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I see what I missed (the fact that it's a list of maps) - I've updated the code accordingly